# jQuery - how to save page elements as variables if html is being reprinted asynchronously

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables, closures, single-page-application

I have a single page app, coded in javascript and jQuery. The content of the page is being reprinted based on the user's interaction. The problem is, I have page elements declared as global variables and they don't work (their value is undefined) as the html is being emptied and filled again.

**Where should I declare page elements if not globally?**

This is the current pattern of my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //GLOBAL VARIABLES
    var $homeLink = $(".home");
    var $userLink = $(".user");  
    var $content = $(".content");
    var $text = $(".content .text"); //this is undefined as the html doesn't exist yet

    //FUNCTIONS
    function printHtml() {  
        $content.empty();
        $('<div />', { class: "text", text: "Lorem" }).appendTo($content);
    }

    //EVENTS
    $homeLink.on("click", function(){
        printHtml();
    });

    $text.on("click", function() { //can't get here because variable $text is undefined
        //do something
    });
});
```

Comment: I guess that you could place the <script> tags of your JS at the end of the html page.

Comment: @joel JS files are at the end of html page. The page html is being reprinted via data from Ajax calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about delegation?

just replace your

```
$text.on("click", function() { //can't get here because variable $text is undefined
        //do something
    });
```

with

```
$content.on('click', '.text', function() {

});
```

and no need in `$text` ( or you always can get it with jQuery in handler if you need ( thus it can be changed, you should refind it on every click )

Comment: Yes, it works for this simple example. But for the single page app, I need to not only attach event listeners to page elements but also pass them around as parameter. Is there no way to be able to save page elements into variables while having dynamic html content?